# Why when clicking a table header to expand/collapse it is doing it for all my tables not just the one clicked?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, html-table

I am creating tables generated from Json in the View of my ASP.Net Core MVC project.  I am using bootstrap to expand/collapse the table when the header is clicked on but when I do so it expands/collapses all of my tables not just the one I am clicking on.  How do I fix this to just show the data in the table that I am clicking the header for?

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @foreach (var i in item.Request.Path.Matchers)
        {
            @if (i.Pattern.Contains("/api.datastore") == false)
            {
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable">
                                <th class="center">Id: @item.Guid</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="accordion" class="collapse">
 
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="label">URL: </span>@i.Pattern</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="label">Body: </span>@item.Response.Body</td>
                                </tr>
 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-target` and `id` are all the same(`accordion`),you need distinguish them like below:

```
@{ 
    var j = 0;   //add this...
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @foreach (var i in item.Request.Path.Matchers)
    {
        @if (i.Pattern.Contains("/api.datastore") == false)
        {
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">

                                                       //change here...
                    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion_@j" class="clickable">
                        <th class="center">Id: @item.Guid</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                           //change here...
                <tbody id="accordion_@j" class="collapse">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="label">URL: </span>@i.Pattern</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="label">Body: </span>@item.Response.Body</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

             j++;   //add this .....

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is about data-target="#accordion" and id="accordion".
Could add some text from @item to the value of data-target and id after "accordion" to identify the relationship.